# Implementing external mergesort. How to get started?

Tags: c++, c, sorting, mergesort

For a project I have to implement an external mergesort algorithm. It will be used to sort a file with mostly numbers or strings and will be some GBs in size. This is the definition of the mergesort that I've been given

```
void MergeSort (char *infile,
                unsigned char field,
                block_t *buffer,
                unsigned int nmem_blocks,
                char *outfile,
                unsigned int *nsorted_segs,
                unsigned int *npasses,
                unsigned int *nios);
```

I'm not allowed to change that. The first argument is the file that I'm going to sort. The second the field according to which I want to sort the file (doesn't interest me right now), the third argument is the buffer. Which is a struct. Here is the definition of a block

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int blockid;
    unsigned int nreserved; // how many reserved entries
    record_t entries[MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK]; // array of records
    bool valid;  // if set, then this block is valid
    unsigned char misc;
    unsigned int next_blockid;
    unsigned int dummy;

} block_t;
```

the fourth argument is the number of blocks in memory. The last three arguments can be set by me.

My questions are:

1. Do I take the file and cut it into two files?
2. Is the buffer a file stored in the harddrive or does it stay in the memory? Do I have to create a new file? I'm a little confused with this part.

These are my thoughts to start right now. First I get the file and split it in two parts. I also create a buffer, which I don't know what size it should have. Then I read the first block of records from the first file, and compare the numbers to the first block of records of the second file. Whenever the number is lesser or equal to another I will send it to the output file. Can you evaluate my stream of thoughts? Or am I thinking it wrong?

Comment: Don't use `..._t` as `typedef`'d names, since they are used by the standard built-in library, and that would lead to confusion.

Comment: First learn how mergesort works: it's a documented algorithm and it isn't clear from the question that you know it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer my github repo - https://github.com/melvilgit/external-Merge-Sort/blob/master/README.md

Problem Stement

All Sorting Algorithm works within the RAM .When the data to be sorted does not fit into the RAM and instead they resides in the slower external memory (usually a hard drive) , this technique is used . Example , If we have to Sort 100 numbers with each number 1KB and our RAM size is 10KB ,external merge sort works like a charm !.

How to ?

Split Phase

Split the 100 KB file into 10 files each 10kb
Sort the 10KB files using some efficient Sorting Algo in O(nlogn)
Stores each of the smaller files to disk .
Merge Phase

Do a K-way merge with each smaller files one by one. Inline the details .

After the Split Phase , A list of file handler of all the splitted files will be stored - sortedTempFileHandlerList

Now, We creates a list of heapnode - heapnodes. Each heapnode will stores the actual entry read from the file and also the file which owns it . The heapnodes is heapified and it will be a min-heap.

Assuming there 10 files , heapnodes will takes 10KB only (each number assume 1KB) .

Loop While Least Element (the top of heap ) is INT_MAX
Picks the node with least element from heapnodes . ( 0(1) since heapnodes is a min heap )
Write the element to sortedLargeFile (it will be the sorted number)
Find the filehandler of the corresponding element by looking at heapnode.filehandler .
Read the next item from the file . If it's EOF, mark the item as INT_MAX
Put the item to heap top . Again Heapify to persist min heap property .
Continue ;
At the end of the Merge Phase sortedLargeFile will have all the elements in sorted order .

Example
Say We have a file largefile with the following Contents

5 8 6 3 7 1 4 9 10 2

In Split Phase ,We Split them into the Sorted chunks in 5 separate temp files.

temp1 - 5 ,8    temp2 - 3 ,6    temp3 - 1, 7    temp4 -4 , 9    temp5 - 2 ,10

Next Construct a Min Heap with top element from each files

```
                     1                       
                   /  \
                  2    5
                /  \                         
               4    3
```

Now picks the least Element from the min heap and write it to sortedOutputFile - 1.
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 1 .
The no is 7 from temp3 . Move it to heap.

```
  7                                    2
/  \                                 /  \
```

2     5      Heapify -->             3    5
  /  \                                 / \
 4    3                               4   7 
Picks the least element 2 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2.
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 2 .
The no is 10 from temp5 . Move it to heap.

```
  10                                   3
/  \                                 /  \
```

3     5      Heapify -->             4    5
  /  \                                 / \
 4    7                               10   7 
Picks the least element 3 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3.
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 3 .
The no is 6 from temp2 . Move it to heap.

```
  6                                   4
/  \                                 /  \
```

4     5      Heapify -->             6    5
  /  \                                 / \
10   7                               10   7 
Picks the least element 4 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3 4.
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 4 .
The no is 9 from temp4 . Move it to heap.

```
  9                                   5
/  \                                 /  \
```

6     5      Heapify -->             6    9
  /  \                                 / \
10   7                               10   7 
Picks the least element 5 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3 4 5.
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 5.
The no is 8 from temp1 . Move it to heap

```
  8                                   6
/  \                                 /  \
```

6     9      Heapify -->             7    9
  /  \                                 / \
10   7                               10   8 
Picks the least element 6 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3 4 5 6 .
Finds the next element of the file which owns min element 5 . .
We have see EOF . So mark the read no as INT_MAX .

INT_MAX                                 7
    /  \                                 /  \
   7    9      Heapify -->              8     9 
  /  \                                 / \
10   8                               10   INT_MAX
Picks the least element 6 and moves it to sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .
If we loop this process , we would reaches a point where , the heap would looks like below and the
sortedOutputFile - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .
We would also breaks at this point when the min element from heap becomes INT_MAX .

```
                   INT_MAX                       
                    /   \
                INT_MAX  INT_MAX
                /    \                         
             INT_MAX INT_MAX
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution depends on the size of input file.

What I would do is to check the size of the file first, if it's smaller than certain size, for example, 1GB (providing 1GB is a small amount of memory on your machine), then I'll read the whole file, store the content in memory, merge sort them, then write to the new file.

Otherwise, I'll have to divide the original file to K temp files less than 1GB, merge sort each of them, then do a K way merge sort between the files, and finally concats the K files together. Basically you need to divide and conquer in two levels, first the files on disc, then the contents in memory.

Comment: The file will for sure be more than 1GB. How do I use the buffer?Any ideas?

Comment: buffer will store the entries you are trying to sort in memory, you can start with a small file, implement your merge sort algorithm, then worry about bigger files.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using any reasonable OS (anything with an X in it or BSD) and have enough memory rely on 'sort'. If you hit the limit on file size, use 'split' and then the --merge option of sort to merge the already sorted files.
2. If you really need to write code for an external sort you can save yourself a lot of trouble by starting with a thorough reading of Knuth's TAOCP Vol III, Chp 5 on external sorting.